# How do I connect MATLAB to Astra DB?

Tags: matlab, cassandra, datastax-astra

I have developed a database on Astra db, a DaaS application. I ran into some issues trying to connect it to MATLAB and would like some possible explanations and maybe solutions as to why this happened.

I tried using a secure bundle and an ODCB driver. However, I was not able to connect to the database on either approach.

If any further information is needed, comment and I will update this post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll need to provide additional details so others can help you. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following articles a read if you haven't already...

- [Import Data from Cassandra Database Table Using CQL](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/import-data-from-cassandra-database-table-using-cql-and-apache-cassandra-database-cplusplus-interface.html)
- [apacheCassandra](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/apachecassandra.html)
- [DataStax Astra DB Serverless Documentation > Manage application tokens](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/manage/org/manage-tokens.html#_create_application_token)
- [Connect with legacy drivers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/connect/drivers/legacy-drivers.html#_php_legacy_drivers)

Give the following a try...

**Step-1:** From the Astra console, generate an application token - see [Manage application tokens](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/manage/org/manage-tokens.html#_create_application_token) for guidance. To make things simple, the token's role to "Administrator User". Save the client id, client secret, and token. You'll need them later.

**Step-2:** From the Astra console, download the secure-connection-bundle for your database. From the main dashboard, click on your database, choose the Connect tab, and click the Download Bundle button.

**Step-3:** Unzip the secure connection bundle and open the `config.json` file. Pull the host and port from the file.

**Step-4:** In Matlab, script your connection and query out. You'll need the Database Toolbox if you're trying this from Matlab online.

```
datasource = "CassandraDataSource";
username = "<client_id>";
password = "<client_secret>";
conn = apacheCassandra(datasource, username, password, 'ContactPoints', <host>, 'PortNumber', <port>, 'SSLEnabled', true);

query = strcat("SELECT whatevs ", ... 
    "FROM keyspace.table ", ...
    "WHERE primary_key IN ('foo','bar')";

results = executecql(conn, query);

close(conn)
```

Good luck!